# Operator that is the limit of a sequence of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, dual-spaces

Let $X$ be Banach and $Y$ be a reflexive space with $T_n \in \mathscr{L}(X,Y)$ so that $\Lambda (T_nx) $ converges for all $x \in X$ and $\Lambda \in Y^{*}$.

Then there exists a  $T \in \mathscr{L}(X,Y)$ so that $\Lambda (Tx) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Lambda(T_nx)$ for all $x \in X$ and $\Lambda \in Y^{*} $.

I have already proven that for a Banach space $X$ and normed $Y$ the pointwise limit of a linear continous operator is again linear and continous but I am just not getting forward here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $x$ in $X$, consider the linear map
$$
  \varphi _x:\Lambda \in  Y^*\mapsto \lim_{n\to \infty }\Lambda \big (T_n(x)\big )
  $$
By the  Banach-Steinhaus theorem we have that $\varphi _x$ is continuous, so $\varphi _x\in Y^{**}$.  Since $Y$ is reflexive there must
be some vector $T(x)$ in $Y$ such that
$$
  \varphi _x(\Lambda ) = \Lambda \big (T(x)\big ),\quad \forall \Lambda \in  Y^*.
  $$
It then follows that
$$
  \Lambda \big (T(x)\big ) = \varphi _x(\Lambda ) = \lim_{n\to \infty }\Lambda \big (T_n(x)\big ).
  $$
Can you pick up from here and prove that $T$ is bounded?

Comment: Thank you. Since we know that $\lim_{n\to \infty }\Lambda \big (T_n(x)\big )$ converges there must be a $C$ so that $|\Lambda (T_n(x))| \le C$ and therefore we have $$||T(x)|| = \lim_{n\to \infty} ||T_n(x)|| \le C||x||$$. This implies that $||T|| \le C$ already.

Comment: Did you pick $C$ after fixing $x$?  If so $C$ might depend on $x$ and in this case the proof is not correct.

Comment: Thanks i got it now. I can first pick one dependent on x and then work straight forward for the general case like i did with another proof. Thank you again